# Cannot commit transaction with PDO connection in Laravel

Tags: php, pdo, transactions, mariadb

So I have an sqldump.sql file that I want to execute on a newly created database inside a Laravel PHP script.

So after i successfully created the new Database i connect to it using PDO:

```php
$db = new PDO("mysql:dbname=$dbName;host=$host;charset=utf8", $envUsername, $envPassword);
```

After this I do the following:

```php
if (file_exists($sqldumpPath)) {
  $db->beginTransaction();
  try {
    $result = $db->exec(file_get_contents($sqldumpPath));
    $db->commit();
  } catch(PDOException $e) {
    $db->rollBack();
  }
}
```

When I run this code Laravel throws an PDOException with message

`PDOException: There is no active transaction`
on the line containing `$db->commit()`

But the entire sqldump is imported and all the tables are created and populated, so how come there are no active transactions?!

PHP: 8.1.12
Laravel: 9.38.0
Mysql: version 15.1 Distrib 10.5.16-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 5.2

Comment: Check your dump file. If it has `LOCK TABLES` and `UNLOCK TABLES`, it may commit the transaction. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/lock-tables.html - See the **Interaction of Table Locking and Transactions** section

Comment: Or any DDL statement (e.g. create / alter / drop) would cause an implicit commit. Btw, Mariadb is **not** mysql.

Comment: @aynber && Shadow Yes I do have both CREATE statements and LOCK TABLES in the dump. It's a wordpress DB I'm trying to establish.. So does it mean that I do not need the transaction/commit syntax? Does it already 'rollback' if something goes wrong?

Comment: That is correct, you don't need them, since those lines will take precendence.

Comment: No, you cannot roll back database structure changes. You have to drop or alter back the database objects you created / altered. I really would not use a php app to seed a wordpress database. Use a proper mysql client.

Comment: @shadow Why? It's supossed to be created and seeded from a web frontend in my use case

Comment: Web scripts supposed to run for a couple of seconds at most. Seeding a database will take a lot more than that. This should be done in a background process, in which case php  is just an unnecessary complication. You can use the frontend to trigger a background process, if you want the user to be able to seed a database.

Comment: @shadow Then i won't be able to catch exceptions and stuff like that... Well things seems to work great, and only takes a second.. even though I should probably have used Python or something instead

Comment: You can catch exceptions in background processes as well.